New Ubuntu dual boot will forcefully suspend with distorted audio
I just made an office computer dual bootable with Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10 on a separate SSD. Everything worked fine. I was able to listen to music on the speakers, but the next day when logging in to Ubuntu I started having distorted audio from my speakers with the audio icon muting and unmuting itself.
Then the computer will forcefully lock out/suspend. What I mean by this is the screen will go black, my monitors will display the same message as if I turned them on while the computer is off and the power light on the computer power on/off button will turn off. Usually the computer will turn on again automatically to the user login screen after a while. Sometimes I need to press a keyboard key to get there.
Occasionally when typing my password to login the key inputs are not registered. If I can log back in the computer works for a few minutes before repeating the cycle. At other times just typing in my password will initiate the cycle again. The same is occurring with the Windows 10 now. I've noticed when I enter the UEFI inputs from my keyboard they aren't registered, but I can still use my mouse. Does this sound like a hardware malfunction?

Made edits describing the occurances, hopefully this is more comprehensive.

Power light change suggests an unexpected poweroff. Ubuntu does not tell your system to poweroff unexpectedly (who would want such a feature?) There are several possible causes, but they are all hardware-related: Heat, power supply, etc.

"The same is occurring with the Windows 10 now" in your question suggests that there is some sort of hardware problem that affects both Windows 10 and Ubuntu as you mentioned in the last sentence of your question. Obviously it's a problem with the keyboard because you can do the same action with your mouse without any problem.
Office managers like to provide their workers with special keyboards that have several function keys "to improve productivity". Maybe one of these function keys is malfunctioning. I suggest connecting a different keyboard, preferably a "normal" keyboard.
